# Song played in Tokyo Ghoul :re episode 4

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

The soundtrack starts when Juzu enters the Auction, attacks the ghouls and then looks up at the Madam (duration 09:40-10:52)

Answer (score 3):

The soundtrack has not been publicly released as of yet. When the season is finished I assume we will know ;) (Though the ED and OP have been)

### If my math is correct, the earliest it will be released is in 53 days and 4 hours (from when this is posted).

This is if they actually release the OST on that day, they might release it the weeks afterwards; who knows?